# Beginner in python(loop map)

Tags: python, loops

#I want to create a map:
[loop map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHU0m.png)

#This is the codes that I tried:

```
x=input("Is't rainning?: ")
if x == "Yes" == "yes":
    x=input("Have a umbrella?: ")
elif x == "No" == "no":
    print("Go out")
```

Comment: for the condition use : `if x in ("Yes","yes")` because what you do there is to test `if x == "Yes" and "Yes" == "yes"` so it's always `false`

Comment: def r():
    x = input ('raining: ')
    while x == 'Yes':
        y= input ('have umbrella:')
        if y =='Yes':
            break 
        elif y == "No":
            print('wait')
            rain()
            break
            
    return 'go out'

Comment: Try this solution